# Clean up After killing process

Tags: c#, winforms, process

I have an application that connects to KepServerEx. When it connects KepServer, KepServer says 1 Client is connected to Server. But if i kill my application using process.Kill() method KepServer still says There is a client connected to Server.

How can i release resources after i killed my process?

Edit : My application try to kill all other intances of process if exist at first run. So i try to kill process from another instance

Comment: maybe closing a connection before killing a proces?

Comment: I am killing process from another instance of process

Comment: The typical pattern is to kill any "connection" that hasn't been used in a while. This is called "Timeout". The typical workaround for the server prematurely killing connections is to have the client send a message periodically. This is called "HeartBeat" (not to be confused with "HeartBleed", which was a massive bug in the OpenSSL HeartBeat).

Answer (score 1):

It's technically impossible since the call to Process.Kill is an OS call that talks directly to the process's kernel object and kills it. Since the main thread is destroyed no matter how low you go (C, ASM) there is nothing you can do about that. 
And even if you could what happens when there is a sudden power cutout? My point is that it's the server's duty to managed connectivity with it's clients, the clients should help but the server can never relay blindly on them.